# Sum list of dictionary ticked box

Tags: python, list, dictionary, box

I have a list of 30 menus:

```
MENUS = [
  {
    "name": "Pates carbonara",
    "pasta (g)": 100, 
    "egg": 2, 
    "cheese (g)": 50, 
    "pork (g)": 50,
  },
  {
    "name": "Pates cacio e pepe", 
    "pasta (g)": 100, 
    "cheese (g)": 40,
    "pepper": 1,
},


"name": "Salmon teriyaki", 
    "salmon (g)": 125,
    "soya": 1,
    "ginger (g)": 10,
    "sesame (g)": 5,
    "pepper": 1,
    "sugar": 1,

etc...
```

and I would like to have as a result --> the sum of the ingredients:

```
pasta = 200
cheese= 40
etc...
```

My goal is for the user to have a list of the different menus and when they select the menus they have the sum of the ingredients. 
How can I do that? 
I successfully did it but my algorithm doesn't sum the values which are selected but only take the value of the first menu selected.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Go with pandas here:  `pd.DataFrame(MENUS).iloc[:,1:].sum(0).to_dict()`

Comment: The ingredients are not the same in each `dict`, so why mark it as a duplicate tho?